# CodeIgniter, call another function after $this- response

Tags: api, codeigniter

I am using Rest library and have the following function as below:-

```
function post_rayz(){
$one = $this->testone();
if($one == 1){
$this->sendSMS();
}
}  
function testone(){
$this->response(['status' => 1, 'message' => 'success 4'], 200);    
}

function sendSMS(){
echo "two";
}
```

When i get a response from function testone() the script stops and is not going to sendSMS() function.

I want to sendSMS after successfully complete testone()

Any help will be most welcome. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the order of operations or if sending that SMS is time consuming maybe you can add it to a queue and process it later. By calling `$this->response()` you end the request by sending a response to user.

LE:
Have a look on `fastcgi_finish_request()` to see if you can tweak the framework.

Answer (score 0):

you have to return your response

```
function testone(){
 return $this->response(['status' => 1, 'message' => 'success 4'], 200);    
}
```

$one is array , you must check the status

```
if($one[0]['status'] == 1){
 $this->sendSMS();
}
```

Comment: Hi, yes i have done this and the result is 1. Even then the script stops and does not go further. I think its something to do with $this->response. Cannot find any documentation also.